# Why successful ping $link returns nothing on query (ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I'm trying to implement a "like" button with ajax so I don't have to reload the page to update the database, but no query done through ajax works.

I have it stripped down to just checking if the user already liked this project or not and I still don't manage to make it work.

I have validated:

-The $link is good (through mysqli_ping())

-The query itself is good (through phpMyAdmin)

-The ajax seems good too (replacing echo $val to echo 1 or echo memberId alert the good value).

code.js:

```
$("#likebtn").click(function(){

    //check if already liked
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"extra/projectpagefunctions.php",
        data: {func: 'existsLinkProject', Table: 'projectLikes'},
        success : function(result){

            alert(result);

        },
        error : function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

projectpagefunctions.php:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $TestLink = mysqli_connect('localhost', '*******', '******', '******');

    function existsLinkProject($Table){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `".$Table."` WHERE `memberId` = ".$_SESSION["account"]["memberId"]." AND `idProject` = ".$_SESSION["project"]["idProject"];
        $result = mysqli_query($TestLink, $query);

        $val=0;

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
            $val=1;
        }

        echo $val;

    }


    if(isset($_POST["func"]) && mysqli_ping($TestLink)){

        if($_POST["func"] == "existsLinkProject"){
            existsLinkProject($_POST["Table"]);
        }

    }
    else{
        echo "error";
    }
?>
```

I would expect the function to return 1 if already liked, and 0 if not.
But I only get 0 no matter what is in the database.

(on loading of the page I check it and set the color of the button accordingly and this already works)

Comment: in projectpagefunctions.php you shloud echo $val instead of $query.

Comment: Yeah sorry error in copy pasting, echo $val is what my code does. I'm editing it

Comment: (Just to specify, this was NOT the problem)